# Android: TextView on the Mapview Programmatically

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-view

How do I inflate the textview with address on the mapview programmatically?

Note: I do not need the textview onCLick/onTap. I just want to show the textview as soon as the map loads.

Thanks,
Sowmya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to have the text be tied to some geographical coordinate, so if the user scrolls the map the text moves with it, you will need to create a custom `Overlay` that paints the text in the desired spot.

If, on the other hand, you simply want some text to overlay the map in a fixed location (e.g., upper-right corner), put the `MapView` and a `TextView` as children of a `RelativeLayout`. Position the `TextView` where you want, and make sure it is a later child of the `RelativeLayout` (e.g., in XML, it is later in the file). `RelativeLayout` supports Z-axis ordering, and so the `TextView` will float over the map.

Comment: @Commonsware- I want to pin the mapballoon with address instead of using  a marker. I also need ot know how to paint the text to fit in the balloon. thanks.

Comment: @Sowmya: "I want to pin the mapballoon with address instead of using a marker" -- that makes no sense. " I also need ot know how to paint the text to fit in the balloon" -- people usually size the balloon to fit the text. There's an open source map balloons library for Android floating around that you may wish to take a look at.